# What's the purity of random clustering?

Tags: clustering, expected-value, multi-class, metric

[Purity is defined](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html) as 
$\mbox{purity}(
\Omega,\mathbb{C}
) =
\frac{1}{N}
\sum_k \max_j
\vert\omega_k \cap
c_j\vert$

where  $\Omega = \{ \omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots, \omega_K \}$is the set of clusters and  $\mathbb{C} = \{ c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_J \}$ is the set of classes.

If we assign points randomly to cluster, **what is the expected purity?**

The answer is important, so we can make sense of the purity by itself when evaluating a clustering method.

Yes, information-based metrics are easier to understand in this context, but purity is very popular.

Comment: What set of values do $w_k$ and $c_j$ take on?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the size of the class is the same.  In that case,

$\vert\omega_k \cap c_j\vert = \frac{N}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert}
\frac{1}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert}$

where the first term is the expected size of a cluster $k$, and the second is the expected proportion of them to be in class $j$. Then,

$\max_j \vert\omega_k \cap c_j\vert = \frac{N}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert}
\frac{1}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert}$

as all sets have the expected same size, that does not depends on $j$. Finally,

$\mbox{purity}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}) = 
\frac{1}{N} \vert \Omega \vert
\frac{N}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert^2} = 
\frac{\vert \Omega \vert}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert^2}$

Further, if the number of classes and clusters is the same, then

$\mbox{purity}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}) = \frac{1}{\vert\mathbb{C}\vert}$

So, if the expected purity became relevant if the number of classes is small.

If $\Omega$ grows, keeping $\mathbb{C}$ fixed, then random clustering gets easier. Beware of $\Omega$ growing too much, as this argument would stop making sense.